# Bits confusion on unary complement operator

Tags: bit

Bitwise unary complement operator (~) of 2 is -3. I read some where the value 2 in binary representation is 0010 and Bitwise unary complement operator changes bits from 0 to 1, or vice versa. So the value of ~2 is 1101. it means -3. But my confusion is why have they taken 2's binary representation as 0010. according to me int is 32bits. so why 2 cant be 00000000000000000000000000000010 and it's unary complement is 11111111111111111111111111111101? I know am wrong but why? please explain?

Comment: who told you it has to be 32bit's?

Comment: It all depends what is `int` in this context.

Comment: one can represent a number with any number of bits he pleases. if there aren't enought bits then you have a problem.

Comment: also complement of 2 doesn't necessarily has to be -3. If you use 4 bits to encode only positive integers than it would be 13

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **"Two's complement was chosen over one's complement because of several convenient characteristics making arithmetic easier to implement in digital circuits"**.

I believe from the wording of your question that a bit of an illustration would help.

To fully appreciate this, you still need to read up on two's complement notation and arithmetic - both how they work and their history - but I will try to explain the basics here in a story-like fashion.

Let's say that we have 4 bits in which to represent a signed integer value.

- Only 16 distinct values can be represented in 4 bits (16 distinct
  different "patterns" can be made with 4-bits)... 0000, 0001, 0010,
  0011, 0100, ... 1111 (try it, it's easier to see and develop the
  pattern in a columnar format, which you'll see I've done below)
- Decide which 16 values you want to be able to represent
- It makes sense to say that 0000 stands for zero, 0001 for one, and so on for positives, but what about negatives?
- Because zero has "taken one place", we can represent 15 other integers so it is immediately obvious that we cannot represent the same amount of positive and negative values.
- We make a choice: our range will run from -8 to +7 (we might have said -9 to +6 or -7 to +8 etc but you'll see below how this choice pays off)
- Now which bit-patterns should represent the negatives?
- I'm sure you'll agree that it would be very nice if every number added to its additive inverse gave zero without us needing to resort to if-negative-then-else(if positive) logic. E.g. If +3 is represented 0011 and we do (binary) addition of 1101 we get the result (carry 1)0000. Ignore the carry and we've got zero. This makes the bit pattern 1101 obvious winner of the tag "-3".
- You can play with the remaining values the same way and what you should arrive at is the following...

  `-8 1000
  -7 1001
  -6 1010
  -5 1011 
  -4 1100 
  -3 1101 
  -2 1110 
  -1 1111 
   0 0000 
  +1 0001 
  +2 0010 
  +3 0011 
  +4 0100 
  +5 0101 
  +6 0110 
  +7 0111`

With the following beautiful and convenient characteristics

- "Natural counting bit patterns". Look down the column on the far right and you'll see 0 1 0 1..., then 0 0 1 1... in the next column, then 0 0 0 0 1...  etc running perfectly in sequence into the positives
- Incrementing "wraps around" (0,1,2,...7,-8,-7,-6,...-1,0,1,...etc and the same goes for decrementing)
- Binary addition of additive inverses gives zero with no extra logic to deal with signs
- All negative numbers have 1 for their first bit, zero and all positive numbers start with a 0. (The first bit is referred to as "the sign bit".)
- Additive inverses can be obtained by the following rule/algorithm: "Invert all bits, increment, discard carry". Magic! Try 3 again:

  `3 : 0011
  ~ : 1100 (the NOT operator gives "one's complement")
  +1: 1101 (the two's complement representation of -3)
  ~ : 0010
  +1: 0011 (back to +3)
  etc`
- This is two's complement notation

If you've understood this 4-bit story, you'll find that it can be easily extended to apply to 32 bit signed integers.